# Python how to add number to string

Tags: python

i want to add numbers in my url
to look like this : 
www.exemple.com/001
www.exemple.com/002
 ...
www.exemple.com/009
www.exemple.com/010
...
www.exemple.com/100
www.exemple.com/101
so i create this script in python

```
 url = 'www.exemple.com/'
 for x in my_range(0, 10, 1):
    if y<10:
     y='00'+y
    elif y<100:
     y='0'+y
    else:
     pass
  url+=str(y)
  print url
```

but i have this error :

```
 IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

any ideas ho to fix this and thanks a lot guys.

Comment: use str(number) to convert number to string. `y='00'+str(y)`

Comment: `url+=str(y)` and `print url` are not indented correctly.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Why isn't this an answer?

Comment: @sfdcfox I guess it would be better to close this question as it "was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error".

Comment: The answer can also been straightforwardly deduced by reading the error message.

Comment: Check out [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide - use 4 spaces for indentation, not 1. You'll be able to align things much more easily.

Comment: True enough. I usually give a benefit of the doubt for Python, because it's the only commonly used (eh, as far as I'm concerned) language that specifically requires spacing as syntax, and not simply a grammar suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think you wanted something like

```
url = 'www.exemple.com/'           # <-- For example
for x in xrange(1, 11, 1):
  print url + "{0:03d}".format(x)
```

Which stops at 10 and outputs

```
www.exemple.com/001
www.exemple.com/002
www.exemple.com/003
www.exemple.com/004
www.exemple.com/005
www.exemple.com/006
www.exemple.com/007
www.exemple.com/008
www.exemple.com/009
www.exemple.com/010
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of indentation and logical issue in your code. Following code does what you want.

```
url='www.exemple.com/'
for y in xrange(0, 100, 1):
    if y < 10:
        y = '00' + str(y)
    elif y < 100:
        y = '0' + str(y)
    else:
        pass
    print url + str(y)
```

Comment: no, it still doesn't. Try `for y in xrange(0, 100, 1):` and you won't have to assign `x` to `y`, **and** you'll get numbers going up to 99, otherwise the `elif` section is pointless.